# Casting auto_ptr to void pointer

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I am trying to cast auto_ptr to void pointer in the following manner:

```
void *AM::This2Ctx(std::auto_ptr<AMContext> data)
{
 return reinterpret_cast<void *>(data);
}
```

but i keep getting a compilation error:

```
error: invalid cast from type std::auto_ptr<AMContext> to type void*
```

how can this casting be done correctly? and how can it be used in the opposite way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/get) to access the pointer held by auto-ptr :

```
reinterpret_cast<void *>(data.get());
                             ~~~~~~
```

In addition, [`auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) is deprecated, use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but using .get() will move the memory management back to me, wont it? and how can i cast the other way around?

Comment: No, it won't. It just shows you the address. I think, `static_cast` is better than `reinterpret_cast`, you don't need such a low-level casting.

Comment: @Itzik984 A word of warning: If you get a raw pointer from the smart pointer, that pointer has no knowledge of your original smart pointer. If you try to create a new smart pointer from this raw pointer at a later time, you will end up with a double delete (both the original and the new smart pointer will delete the element).

Comment: @Agentlien Thanks for your comment, just to make sure i understand, if i make a new smart pointer from the one i just used .get() on, i will create a double deletion and by so an error? because this is exactly what i need to do. any solution?

Comment: @Itzik984 If you need to create a new smart pointer from the void* returned by get(), you will get a double delete. In that case, you should instead use release() which will make you responsible for managing it (as you asked previously) until you have created a new smart pointer to hold it.